# Android Studio BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, android-studio

i'm a total beginner in android studio. tried to compile "hello world" program but i keep getting these errors and pleas if you have an answer answer me with steps cuz im still a beginner 
PS: i'm using android studio 1.1

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'd:\Users\User4\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: The error says that a resource is missing. It wants a resource. It is resource hungry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
PS: i'm using android studio 1.1
```

I see the error belongs to aapt. It can be caused of out-of-date version. If restart Android Studio is not working. Please try to get new version of Android Studio. Lastest version is 2.1.

Using old version is error-prone.

Download lastest version here and follow the instruction to install it.

[Download Lastest Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)